# how to access function in different folder in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I have organized Python files in differnt folders:

```
root_dir
  utils/
    some_file.py
  models.py
```

In `some_file.py` I just did this:

```
import models
```

But this is not working. I also updated `some_file.py` with:

```
file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(file_dir)

import models
```

Still i get:

```
import models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

Comment: We have no idea what you put in for `file_dir`. That's possibly what the issue is, so you should include an actual example. Is it in a relative format like `sys.path.append('../')`?

Comment: What is your working directory?

Comment: Similar issue resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: @PeterWood working directory is `root_dir`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Try to import it as follows from within the **some_file.py**:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import models

# Use as follows:

# models.function()
```